# Beugt man jemand oder niemand mit Endung?

Tags: usage, style

Diese Wörter und ihre Varianten findet man ja in vielen Büchern endungslos gebeugt, zum Beispiel:

> Ich habe jemand gesehen. Ist das niemand aufgefallen?

Dies ist absolut korrekt, klingt für mich aber trotzdem falsch. Ich bevorzuge definitiv:

> Ich habe jemanden gesehen. Ist das niemandem aufgefallen?

Diese Form ist ebenfalls erlaubt. [Belles lettres](http://www.belleslettres.eu/artikel/jemand-niemand-deklination.php) erklärt das so, dass die Form gebeugt wird, weil man (fälschlicherweise) diese Wörter für Pronomina hält, leitet aber ausführlich ab, warum es sich um Substantive handelt, die lediglich aufgrund dieses Missverständnisses kleingeschrieben werden, noch aus der Zeit, in der Substantive im Deutschen generell kleingeschrieben wurden. Letztendlich empfehlen sie die endungslose Form:

> Nur die endungslose Deklination setzt die Beugung im älteren Deutsch fort und ist heute syntaktisch einwandfrei.

Gleichzeitig empfehlen sie jedoch eine Form mit Endung für den Dativ, sofern der Autor sich nicht sicher sein kann, dass der Leser den Dativ auch ohne erkennen würde.

Jetzt stellt sich mir jedoch die Frage, ob die Belles lettres nicht den gleichen Fehler begehen wie viele Linguisten: Sie stellen die alte Verwendung eines Wortes über die jüngere Verwendung (die es allerdings auch nicht erst seit gestern gibt).

Sollte man also tatsächlich die endungslose Form bevorzugen? Oder ist die Zeit gekommen, da die Beugung mit Endung erfolgen sollte, weil sich diese jüngere Form durchgesetzt hat? Warum? Gibt es vielleicht auch regionale Unterschiede?

Und wie lernt man deutsche Verben, wenn nicht mit *jdn.*, *jdm.*? :)

Comment: Ich hatte mich vor dem Posten gefragt, ob ich die Erklärung aus den Belles lettres als separate Antwort posten sollte, die ich ja selbst anzweifle, und sie dann gegebenenfalls community-wiki zu machen. Meinung dazu? Erstmal finde ich die Frage so aber besser.

Comment: Ich bevorzuge auch eindeutig die Formen mit Endung

Comment: Hoppla, aus dem Grimm, gerade erst gesehen: "neuerer brauch ist, acc. und dat. nach der pronominalen declination zu bilden, jemanden, jemandem. [...] Lessing 1, 376; sie scheinen mir jemanden zu suchen. [...] Göthe 18, 236. für den dativ jemandem: wenn sie sich etwas vornimmt oder jemandem etwas verspricht." Was genug für Göthe (ja, mit Umlaut :P) und Lessing ist, sollte eigentlich für jeden gut genug sein ;)

Comment: Sehr interessant, aber leider auch sehr subjektiv.

Comment: Sehr interessant. Habe den Link gelesen. Mein Sprachempfinden ist von den gebeugten Varianten geprägt, ich muss mir darüber also erst Gedanken machen.

Comment: @swegi: Ich frage nicht, ob jemand eine bestimmte Form lieber mag. Ich möchte eine Begründung, warum die eine oder die andere Form besser ist. Vielleicht habe ich nur etwas übersehen. Auch die Möglichkeit, dass beide Varianten nicht nur korrekt, sondern auch akzeptabel sind, wäre eine gute Antwort, sofern sie einigermaßen begründet werden kann.

Comment: @OregonGhost: Genau diese Antwort ist ja schon in der Fragestellung impliziert.

Comment: @swegi: Findest du? Eigentlich stelle ich die Verwendung der endungslosen Form komplett als veraltet in Frage. Die Belles lettres können nur begründen, woher diese Form kommt; nicht jedoch, warum man die alte gegenüber der jüngeren bevorzugen sollte oder warum sie nicht überhaupt verschwinden sollte.

Comment: @OregonGhost: Naja, du schreibst dazu "Dies ist absolut korrekt[...]" und "Diese Form ist ebenfalls erlaubt[...]". Welche man dann bevorzugt, finde ich doch recht subjektiv (andere offenbar wiederum nicht).

Comment: Der [verlinkte Artikel dazu](http://www.belleslettres.eu/artikel/jemand-niemand-deklination.php) scheint gestrichen worden zu sein – jedenfalls sehe ich nur ein Inhaltsverzeichnes ohne Inhalt. Hat den jemand noch?

Comment: "unhistorische" Beugung ^^... @k.stm Der (recht kurze) Artikel scheint wohlauf.

Comment: Im Dativ und Genitiv sind die Beugungen eigentlich unumgänglich, weil ohne Beugung Missverständnisse aufkommen: "Sklavenhändler: Ich gebe jemand jemand", wer ist wer? Genitiv funktioniert überhaupt nicht ohne Beugung "Ich habe draußen auf dem Parkplatz jemand Auto angerempelt". Warum soll man dann ausgerechnet beim Akkusativ nicht beugen?

Comment: @tofro: Ich finde die Beugung auch viel besser und bin immer irritiert, wenn ich es in einem Buch ohne lese. Aber offenbar ist es korrekt(er) ohne Beugung bzw. mit endungsloser Beugung und die Lektoren der Verlage sind alle darauf eingestellt.

Answer (score 11):

Wortstamm *man-/mon-/manu-*, in germanischen Sprachen und [dem (Alt-)Indischen](http://de.bab.la/woerterbuch/englisch-hindi/human), zu finden.

**Gothisch**

*aiv manna* (goth. nicht jemand?, verwandt mit lat. *aevum*, Ewigkeit),
noch nicht als selbständiges Wort vorhanden.

**Althochdeutsch**

> erst ahd. hat sich das compositum êo-man, io-man, ia-man entwickelt, in welchem der erste theil den substantivbegriff ins allgemeine oder unbestimmte zieht, [...]
>                                           (Grimm)

**Mittelhochdeutsch**

Alt-/Mittelhochdeutsche "a-Deklination" (starke D.), parallel zu jener von *man* (nhd. Mann, vgl. auch *lamb*):

```
ieman/iemen
iemannes
iemanne
ieman/iemen (der für "man" mögliche Akk. "mannen" wurde ansch. nicht übertragen)
```

Diese Formen halten sich bis ins 16. Jh., wenn auch in anderer Schreibweise. Im 14. beginnt t/d in den Auslaut zu treten. (Seit dem 15. Jh. auch *jemands* im Nominativ, inzwischen ausgestorben.)

**Schon im Mhd. und auch noch im Nhd.**

```
jemand
jemand(e)s
jemand
jemand
```

Das ist jenes Stadium, auf das sich der Artikel von "Belles Lettres" bezieht. Mit *jemand* ist also das passiert, was mit den meisten stark gebeugten Wörtern passiert ist: Nur die Genitivendung hat überlebt (vgl. Baum).

Da *Mann* auch unter diesen Wörtern ist, könnte man meinen, dass *jemandem/jemanden* geauso falsch sei wie *Mannem/Mannen*, womit die "Belesenen" im Recht wären (abgesehen vom vergessenen Genitiv). Aber das reicht wohl kaum für einen Preskriptivismus, denn *jemand* ist eine ganz andere Wortart:

Laut Duden und Wikipedia ist *jemand* ein Indefinitpronomen (welches nur im maskulinen Singular auftritt: <strike>jemand, die...</strike>). Die Entfremdung aus den echten Substantiven (wie Mann, Baum, Lamm etc.) scheint Spielraum für die neue Deklination geschaffen zu haben. Was genau die Sprecherschaft veranlasste, Pronomen anders - pronominal eben - zu deklinieren, ist wohl Stoff für eine andere Frage, aber Tatsache ist, dass sich die neue Art durchgesetzt hat, während die alte überlebt hat (ganz untypisch für Sprachen). Wie auch der Artikel einräumt:

**Neuhochdeutsch**

```
jemand
jemandes
jemandem
jemanden
```

und

```
jemand
jemand(e)s
jemand
jemand
```

Obwohl etwas holprig, ist aus dem Kontext meistens klar, ob *jemand* im Akkusativ oder im Dativ steht. Fehlt also Kontext, wie zB beim Lernen von Verben, ist es ratsam, *jdm./jdn.* zu verwenden. Hier die Wahl zu haben, ist darüber hinaus für das Dichten im Trochäus bzw. Jambus von Vorteil.

Quellen: Grimmsches WB, Duden, Wikipedia und [dieses Buch](http://books.google.at/books?id=uhnj2VPP8rAC&pg=PA49&lpg=PA49&dq=mittelhochdeutsch+deklination+mann&source=bl&ots=ALAWsZwweM&sig=xnz3POfhctolO9x4KGBj3mazMFY&hl=de&sa=X&ei=1HYgVLPWH4bnyQOHnYGoCA&ved=0CCEQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=lamm&f=false).

Answer (score 8):

> Dativ und Akkusativ können mit oder ohne Flexionsendung auftreten *(jemand[em], jemand[en]): Es fiel ihm schwer, jemand / jemandem zu widersprechen.*

(...)

> Der schwache Dativ *jemanden* ist nicht standardsprachlich: *Nichts, was jemandem* (nicht: *jemanden*) *etwas bedeuten könnte.* Im Akkusativ wird die endungslose Form oft vorgezogen: *Haben Sie jemand* (seltener: *jemanden*) *getroffen?*

[Duden - Richtiges und gutes Deutsch, 6. Aufl. Mannheim 2007]

Answer (score 2):

Sprache lebt, auch wenn sie immer wieder in gewisse Regeln gezwungen werden soll/muss/?. Also unterscheidet wieder einmal der Sprachgebrauch diverse vorhandene oder eingebildete Gesellschaftsschichten. Richtig ist in diesem Fall meines Erachtens beides. Es zu werten bzw. gewichten zeigt nur den Versuch an vermeintlich bessere, elegantere oder "gebilderte" Benutzer zu definieren. Wem nützt das? Oder hätte ich für die Unterscheidungsliebhaber jetzt Cui bono schreiben sollen?