# How do I decline "jemand" or "niemand"?

Tags: grammar, usage, pronoun, declension

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Beugt man jemand oder niemand mit Endung?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/723/beugt-man-jemand-oder-niemand-mit-endung)

The declension of indefinitve pronouns *"jemand"* or *"niemand"* seems not to follow strict rules. I can read all of the following:

> Er hat mit **jemandem** gesprochen - Er hat mit **jemand** gesprochen
>   Sie hat **niemanden** gesehen - Sie hat **niemand** gesehen
>   Das ist **niemandes** Schuld - Das ist **niemands** Schuld

From [this question](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/723/beugt-man-jemand-oder-niemand-mit-endung) I learned that not declining may be historically correct. [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/jemand) allows both variants not giving any help on what to prefer.

From a [Google Ngram](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=jemanden,%20jemandem,%20niemanden,%20niemandem&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=8&smoothing=3) we see, that declined variants are increasingly used:

[image]

Answers here express that declension is felt to be appropriate in a written text. Are there still situations where using the non-declined forms are preferable?

Comment: Das hat mir wieder mal niemand gesagt - war aber eigentlich klar, dass es diese Frage schon geben muss.

Comment: *Eigentlich* soll Herr StackExchange-Engine bereits nach dem Eingeben des Titels verwandte Fragen anzeigen, was *meistens* ganz gut klappt (weshalb ich es auf SO mitunter als Alternative zur Suche einsetze). Aber es funktioniert leider nicht immer so gut ;)

Comment: Vielleicht weil eine Frage auf Deutsch, die andere auf Englisch gestellt wurde?

Comment: Ich habe auch den Verdacht, dass die Engine da etwas durcheinander kommt und die falschen Schwerpunkte setzt, andererseits hast du die wesentlichen Schlagworte (jemand/niemand) im Titel verwendet. *Sollte* funktionieren. Vielleicht ein Bug? Die SOStacked-App hat übrigens gerade einen Fix für Sonderzeichen bekommen, damit sie auch mit GL&U funktioniert, nur zwei oder drei Wochen nach meinem Bugreport :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nice point! In fact, both variants seem to be valid (see [<1>](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/InflectionRules/FRegeln-P/Pron-Indef/Pron-jemand3.html), [<2>](https://mein-deutschbuch.de/indefinitpronomen.html), [<3>](https://deutschegrammatik20.de/pronomen/indefinitpronomen/indefinitpronomen-jemand-niemand/) and [<4>](https://grammis.ids-mannheim.de/?v_typ=d&v_id=406#me)), but the only explanation given is (as [Hackworth pointed out already](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/2417/how-do-i-decline-jemand-or-niemand/2418#2418)) that dropping the suffix is common in colloquial language.

**EDIT**: i think it's better to reduce the answer to the statement that both variants are orthographically valid; for deeper discussions, see [this question and following comments and responses](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/723/beugt-man-jemand-oder-niemand-mit-endung).

Comment: +1 nice references - thank you.

Comment: As Hackworth's answer, not true. The suffix was *added* in colloquial language, and it is common for written language to use the form without suffix (see any book, for example).

Comment: hmm - really interesting! Here's an interesting [google ngram chart regarding this question](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=jemanden%2Cjemandes%2Cjemandem%2C+jemand&year_start=1800&year_end=2011&corpus=8&smoothing=3) - so, without doubt, in the year 2300 jemand and jemanden will surely be on the same level ;-)

Comment: @tohuwawohu: Yes, though don't forget that "jemand" competes with "jemanden" *and* "jemandem" in this chart ;) I like the suffixed forms much better, I hope they'll become the right form :D

Answer (score 0):

Jemand/Niemand for Akkusativ or Dativ is at best colloquial; you should not use it in written language.

Niemandes/Jemandes is the correct form to be used as a Genitiv; Niemands/Jemands is again colloquial. It is worth noting that the Genitiv form is rare nowadays. Most people seem to prefer rewording such a sentence to avoid the Genitiv, such as "Daran hat jemand/niemand Schuld"

Comment: [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/jemand) allows both variants without stating that the non-declined forms are colloquial.

Comment: This is not true; Jemand/Niemand for Akkusativ/Dativ is the correct written form. See my linked question for details, and see [Belles Lettres](http://www.belleslettres.eu/artikel/jemand-niemand-deklination.php) for an absurdly detailed explanation ("Die gebeugten Formen sind ganz junge Neuerungen der Umgangssprache.")

Comment: Note that I prefer the suffixed form - I was quite surprised when I found out (here at GL&U (; ) that it is not the better ("gehobenere") form.