# "um.. zu" or "zu" in "help me wash my car"

Tags: grammar, preposition

Suppose I want to say

> I want to find someone who can help me wash my car.

Can I say

> Ich will jemand/jemanden finden/suchen, der mir helfen kann, mein Auto zu waschen.

Do I need an "um" before "mein Auto"? (For the two words for which I provide two alternatives, I think either alternative should work. Is that right?)

Comment: Concerning `finden/suchen`: both are possible, but `Ich will jemanden suchen …` is probably not, what you want to express. I guess you mean `Ich suche jemanden …` = `I'm looking for someone …`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*jemanden* is the accusative case, *jemand* is nominative. *Jemand* is the grammatical object to *finden*, and the accusative is the correct choice here, although I can imagine *jemand* might be acceptable in some dialect.

Both *finden* and *suchen* are possible, but note that they do not quite mean the same - "finding" is successful "searching".

You do not need an extra "um". In fact, if you were to include it, the sentence would end up sounding strange:

> Um mein Auto Auto zu waschen, kann mir dieser Jemand helfen. (In order to wash my car, that "somebody" can help me.)

The relative sentence *um mein...* would likely be interpreted to refer to what precedes it directly, ie to *jemanden*. If you change the word order, the sentence sounds alright to me even with the *um*.

> Um mein Auto zu waschen, will ich jemanden suchen/finden, der mir helfen kann.

Comment: The original sounds indeed better than both your alternatives.

Comment: For declension of *jemand* see: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/2417/how-do-i-decline-jemand-or-niemand - your first paragraph should be edited to reflect this better.