# Niemand oder Niemanden?

Tags: grammatical-case

"Ich kenne niemanden, der diese schwierige Sprache so gut spricht wie Sie."

Here, why do people say *niemanden* instead of *niemand*? After that, the "der", is it Dativ or? But the "spricht" means the person is singular right?

Comment: Related, in German: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/723/beugt-man-jemand-oder-niemand-mit-endung

Comment: Also in English: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/2417/how-do-i-decline-jemand-or-niemand

Comment: After the comma, "der" is Nominativ: "der ... spricht". "I don't know anyone who speaks this difficult language as well as you (do)".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In addition to the previous answer, in the accusative and dative the endingless forms of *jemand/niemand* are also used and common:

> Er hat niemand/niemanden gesehen.
>
> Sie hat jemand/jemandem das Buch gegeben.

So, in your example both varieties are possible:

> Ich kenne niemand/niemanden, der diese schwierige Sprache so gut spricht wie Sie.

**Which form is preferred in writing?**

Most German grammar sources see that they are both equally acceptable in writing e.g., *Duden- Rechtschreibung* [jemand](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/jemand) and [niemand](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/niemand). However, I had to dig deeper into Duden as it is the most respected source, and it turned out -contrary to what is mostly believed- that **endingless forms are more preferred**. I quote from [Duden- Die Grammatik](https://books.google.com/books?id=C59iDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA350&lpg=PA350&dq=allerdings%20wird%20im%20Akkusativ%20oft%20die%20endungslose%20Form%20vorgezogen&source=bl&ots=VB5IG9T2Cm&sig=AA2eKRDWTmHIApgifO1cN8nz16A&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi30ImohY_eAhUOqIsKHdpRDTMQ6AEwAXoECAgQAQ#v=onepage&q=allerdings%20wird%20im%20Akkusativ%20oft%20die%20endungslose%20Form%20vorgezogen&f=false):

> Der Genitiv wird mit *-[e]s* gebildet *(jemand[e]s)*. Im Dativ und Akkusativ kann ein *-em* bzw. ein *-en* angehängt werden *(jemandem], niemanden])*; **allerdings wird im Akkusativ oft die endungslose Form vorgezogen**, ebenso vor *anders* oder einem flektierten Adjektiv:
>
> Es fiel ihr schwer, *jemand/jemandem* zu widersprechen. Ich ... tue, als winke ich *jemand* auf der Straße zu *(Remarque)*. ... von *niemand* so glühend beneidet (Quick). Ich habe *niemand/niemanden* gesehen

Answer (score 4):

*Niemanden* is accusative, that's what *kenne* requires for its object.

*Der* is nominative (singular, yes) because it's the subject of the relative clause.

Answer (score -1):

Look at the following:

Ich kenne ein**en** Mann [Akk.]. **Er** [Nom.] spricht diese Sprache.
-> Ich kenne ein**en** Mann, **der** diese Sprache spricht.

Ich kenne jemand**en** [Akk.]. **Er** [Nom.] spricht diese Sprache. -> Ich kenne jemand**en**, **der** diese Sprache ....

analogous:

Ich kenne niemand**en**, **der** diese Sprache so gut spricht wie Sie.

Wenn User maintains "that they are both equally acceptable in writing", he is mistaken.

*jemand / niemand* instead of *jemanden / niemanden* [Akk.] or *jemandem / niemandem* [Dat.] do occur in colloquial language, but in writing they are sub-standard. When Duden says:

Dativ jemandem, ***auch*** jemand  //  Akkusativ jemanden, ***auch*** jemand

their *auch* describes the status quo, it's what can be observed. It's **not** a carte blanche.