# When is niemanden/jemanden used in the dative?

Tags: dative, pronoun

Related: [Niemand oder Niemanden?](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/47515/43989)

According to Wiktionary and one or two other sources I looked at, *niemand* and *jemand* are either uninflected or take an *-em* ending in the dative case. I was checking the DWDS usage database to see which is more common (too close to call), but it turned up examples with *-en* as well. Here are some from *Die Zeit*:

> Sorgen hatte sie sicher nicht, wer hat die schon, aber dass man existiert und schön ist und nett und alles, ist doch erst wahr, wenn es bei **jemanden** in den Augen steht.
> Es macht natürlich nervös, mit **jemanden** zu wetteifern, den man nicht einordnen kann.
> Unterschätzt wird Nahles in der SPD allerdings von **niemanden**.
> Diese helfe **niemanden**.

Are these examples correct, incorrect, colloquial, or am I getting the case wrong? If correct, is the *-en* always a possible ending for the dative of *jemand*/*niemand*?

Comment: I'm puzzled concerning the *uninflected* statement in Wiktionary. If used as a real pronoun, I would always use the inflected form and restrict the uninflected variant to phrases as *jemand Unbekannten*, *jemand Anderen*.

Comment: @guidot I think, it is actually not the uninflected form, but the Dativ/Akkusativ inflection in the process of loosing their endings. Most famous example: _Keine Macht für Niemand_. But in everyday language I hear constructions like _Ich habe niemand gesehen_ all the time.

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach They're not losing their endings. The endings on *jemand* and *niemand* first appeared in Neuhochdeutsch, as [this answer](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/15814/16570) explains

Comment: @guidot: By uninflected I mean having no *-en* or *-em* ending. Also from *Die Zeit*: *Das würde er nie tun bei jemand, den er für einen Versager hält.* Wiktionary says using the inflected forms "is probably somewhat more common (at least in writing)." The fact that the uninflected form is used in front of adjectival nouns was mentioned in Wiktionary and some of the grammars I looked at, for example [LEOs deutsche Grammatik](https://dict.leo.org/grammatik/deutsch/Wort/Pronomen/FRegeln-P/Pron-Indef/Pron-jemand3.xml?lang=de#id=1.5.1.7.14)

Comment: @Numeri Thank you for the hint - very interesting! You are right, they are not even _losing_ their endings, the -em and en ending for Akkusativ and Dative are maybe not even fully established. The comment for guidot remains, that this does not mean it was an uninflected form.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My inclination is to dismiss *von niemanden, mit jemanden* and the like as errors. I cannot recall ever having heard such forms; the dative either has no ending or the ending *‑m*. One would assume that the source of the error lies in the fact that the letters *m* and *n* are adjacent on keyboards and that it is a mistake that spell checkers will not point out.

Having said that, the ending *‑n* in the dative occurs with such surprising frequency that the Duden grammar explicitly mentions it under paragraph 424:

> Im Dativ tritt außerdem die Endung *‑en* auf, zwar seltener als *‑em*, aber doch in recht hoher Frequenz, wie eine Korpusuntersuchung des IDS zeigt.

The study mentioned is reported in https://grammis.ids-mannheim.de/fragen/4332. With *bei*, *mit*, *von*, *zu*, forms with *‑n* instead of expected *-m* occur with a frequency of at least 1 in 15, going up to 1 in 10.

Adding to the mystery is the fact that the ending *‑n* in the dative was possible historically. DWB [jemand](https://www.woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB?lemid=J00786) has two examples (under 3b):

> von iemanden anders erfahren haben
>
> acht tage habe ich dazu einen ausschlag über den ganzen körper gehabt, dasz ich mich kaum vor jemanden sehen lassen konnte

The possibility of having *‑n* in the dative is mentioned by Hermann Paul, *Deutsche Grammatik*, vol. 3, § [138](https://www.digitale-sammlungen.de/de/view/bsb11022621?page=196):

> Die Flexion war im Mhd. die eines regelmäßigen Substantivums, also G. *iemannes*, D. *iemanne*, A. *ieman*. Diese Flexionsweise setzt sich bis auf den heutigen Tag fort, nur daß sich für den Dat. ausschließlich die Form mit Abwerfung des *e* festgesetzt hat. Aber daneben ist seit dem 17. Jahrh. adjektivische Flexion aufgekommen, A. *niemanden*, D. *niemandem* und *niemanden*, Formen, die jetzt ebenso üblich sind wie die älteren.

The ending *‑n* could be interpreted as a weak adjective ending or a weak nominal ending; the fact that it occurs at all is mysterious. (In other contexts, *‑n* can substitute for expected *‑m*, but only when preceded by another word ending in *‑m*; see the Duden grammar under paragraph 1527.) Given the fact that most modern grammars do not mention this form at all, I would treat occurrences of *‑n* in newspapers as simple mistakes.

Comment: So the upshot, as I see it, is that it's an error but a common one that's been documented. And while it seem to have some historical precedent, it is, at best non-standard in Modern German. I take your point that spell checkers would not catch this; being a horrible speller myself I'm very familiar with English misspellings that spell checkers miss (capital/capitol, canon/cannon, etc.) I'd be surprised if a grammar checker didn't catch it, but I suppose they aren't foolproof either.

Comment: I updated the relevant usage notes in Wiktionary. There is still a bit of a mystery about why this is so common, but I'll leave that as a problem for the grammar police. I was mainly concerned that there might be something I was missing, a plural form for example. If it's just an error which, for whatever reason, happens to be common, then that's all I need to know.

Answer (score 9):

All of the examples are wrong. Dative case is required for

> **bei** jemande**m**

> **mit** jemande**m**

> **von** jemande**m**

and

> jemande**m** **helfen**

There is no dative form of *jemand* ending with *-en*.

Comment: *Jemanden* would be a correctly formed accusative, however, as in *Ich sehe jemanden*.

Comment: I wouldn't have asked if this occurred only a few times. But *mit jemanden* appears 29  times in *Die Zeit*, and 20 times in *Berliner Zeitung*. This is only about 10% the rate that *mit jemandem* occurs, but I would have thought that editors of major newspapers would have caught this kind of thing nearly all the time.

Comment: It's a very common error in German and it even happens to quality newspapers.

Comment: @Thomas Wana: I guess it's an error, but frequent enough that it's starting to border on an accepted variation. If enough people do it wrong then it becomes allowed but not preferred, if more people do it then it becomes preferred, and if still more do it becomes mandatory. Thus the language evolves.

Comment: @RDBury It's not something, that becomes allowed because language evolves. It's clearly an error and I'm really surprised (if not shocked) that it happens so often in a newspaper like *Die Zeit*. *Jemande**n*** is accusative. Maybe it's because of *jemand* that can be used for dative and accusative and somehow the *-en* gets added to avoid using *jemand*? I don't know.

Answer (score 1):

There is no situation in which *jemanden* can be used after a dative preposition. If this occurs in text, it's a typo or a case of faulty OCR or transliteration of a source. The only valid forms of *jemand* in the dative case are *jemand* itself or *jemandem*.

---

Interestingly, as an aside, *jemand* predates *jemandem*, with the latter not occuring until New High German, which started around 1650 A.D. [This answer](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/723/beugt-man-jemand-oder-niemand-mit-endung/15814#15814) (not mine) explains that in more detail.

---

With that aside out of the way, I have to admit that your question made me curious. I've never seen someone make a mistake like that in writing – or maybe I've just never noticed!

Using the [DWDS corpora](https://www.dwds.de/r), I searched for all occurrences of the form `<dative-preposition> jemand|jemandem|jemanden`. Unfortunately, I couldn't get the boolean OR operator working well, so I had to search for each combination separately. To recreate my data, make sure to search using the syntax `@mit @jemanden`, which ensures exact matches for each word.

The following table shows the relative frequency of each version of *jemand* after all dative prepositions which make sense in conjunction with *jemand* (I did not include *seit* or *ab*, for instance). It also includes the total number of such constructions found.

While it's still certain that these occurrences are errors, I do find it interesting that they occur so commonly in the DWDS data.

| Preposition | *jemand* | *jemandem* | *jemanden* | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| aus | 23.53 % | 52.94 % | 23.53 % | 34 |
| außer | 85.71 % | 0 % | 14.29 % | 7 |
| bei | 16.53 % | 76.15 % | 7.32 % | 369 |
| gegenüber | 35.71 % | 57.14 % | 7.14 % | 28 |
| mit | 17.27 % | 73.71 % | 9.02 % | 1963 |
| nach | 15.38 % | 77.83 % | 6.79 % | 221 |
| von | 28.72 % | 61.36 % | 9.92 % | 2047 |
| zu | 24.32 % | 64.21 % | 11.48 % | 366 |

---

**Addendum**

The raw data I collected (I excluded certain corpora to avoid low quality sources or what might have been repeated data, i.e., the metacorpora):

| prep | pronoun | DWDS-Kernkorpus (1900–1999) | DWDS-Kernkorpus 21 (2000–2010) | DTA-Kernkorpus (1598–1913) | Berliner Zeitung (1994–2005) | Der Tagesspiegel (ab 1996) | Die ZEIT (1946–2018) | Blogs |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| aus | jemand | 1 | 0 | 0 | 2 | 1 | 3 | 1 |
| aus | jemandem | 1 | 0 | 0 | 4 | 2 | 7 | 4 |
| aus | jemanden | 2 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 2 | 2 |
| außer | jemand | 0 | 0 | 0 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 4 |
| außer | jemandem | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| außer | jemanden | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| bei | jemand | 13 | 1 | 3 | 4 | 6 | 13 | 21 |
| bei | jemandem | 17 | 8 | 1 | 34 | 37 | 126 | 58 |
| bei | jemanden | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 5 | 19 |
| gegenüber | jemand | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 7 | 1 |
| gegenüber | jemandem | 2 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 10 | 2 |
| gegenüber | jemanden | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| mit | jemand | 65 | 3 | 80 | 18 | 17 | 80 | 76 |
| mit | jemandem | 125 | 43 | 3 | 195 | 162 | 688 | 231 |
| mit | jemanden | 3 | 1 | 27 | 20 | 9 | 29 | 88 |
| nach | jemand | 8 | 2 | 4 | 3 | 4 | 11 | 2 |
| nach | jemandem | 15 | 4 | 0 | 25 | 18 | 84 | 26 |
| nach | jemanden | 1 | 0 | 3 | 4 | 1 | 2 | 4 |
| von | jemand | 74 | 8 | 182 | 32 | 27 | 141 | 124 |
| von | jemandem | 81 | 25 | 9 | 159 | 110 | 564 | 308 |
| von | jemanden | 7 | 1 | 83 | 4 | 9 | 13 | 86 |
| zu | jemand | 17 | 3 | 19 | 4 | 2 | 32 | 12 |
| zu | jemandem | 20 | 10 | 3 | 31 | 30 | 104 | 37 |
| zu | jemanden | 3 | 0 | 5 | 3 | 2 | 9 | 20 |

Comment: I'd throw any queries with less that 5 result; there's often some twist of phrasing that allows two words to meet in some unexpected way. Your results do prove that the inflected form is more common than the uninflected form, something was unsure of from a visual inspection. They also support what I was saying that the *en* ending is occurring more often then I'd expect for a simple typographical error.