# Jemand eine kleben - was ist die „eine“?

Tags: etymology, colloquial, proverb

Ich kenne den Ausdruck *jemand eine kleben* als umgangssprachlichen Begriff für eine [Ohrfeige](https://dwds.de/wb/Ohrfeige) verteilen.

> Pass bloß auf, ich kleb' dir gleich eine!

In den einschlägigen Wörterbüchern ([Grimm](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GK06735#XGK06735), [DWDS](https://dwds.de/wb/kleben)) ist diese Bedeutung aber nicht, oder nur als Anhang ([Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/kleben)) gelistet.

Ist *eine kleben* nur ganz regional bekannt? Was ist in diesem Ausdruck die „eine“ und was **klebt** dann hier?

---

Vielleicht noch erwähnenswert ist, dass der Ausdruck gelegentlich mit *waschen* verknüpft wird:

> Sie klebte ihm eine, die sich gewaschen hat.

Comment: Dein Duden Link: "Wendungen, Redensarten, Sprichwörter
jemandem eine kleben (salopp: jemandem eine Ohrfeige geben)"

Comment: @Iris: danke, das ist ja ganz ganz unten, kaum zu sehen ;)

Comment: ich hab noch "eine" im Text gesucht. Es hatte mich gewundert, dass der Duden es nicht gelistet haben sollte.

Comment: Es ist möglicherweise interessant, dass es im Französischen mit *je vais t'en coller une...* eine praktisch wörtliche Übersetzung davon gibt. Vielleicht muss man in der Richtung suchen.

Comment: Und das ist ein weit verbreitetes Phänomen, das nicht nur aufs Kleben bezogen ist: *Er lacht sich eins*, *er pfeift sich eins*, *er holt sich einen runter*,... Meistens ist da auch nicht klar, was das "eine" denn nun ist.

Comment: Eventuell ist *eins* bzw. *eine* hier mit *ein, rein*  gleichzusetzen (Vgl. *Einsicht* "insight"), jedoch als "eine (Backpfeife)" o.ä. verstanden. Nicht zu verwechseln mit *einkleben*, etwa "ein Foto *in* ein Album *kleben*".

Answer (score 4):

Die Formulierung ist Umgangssprache und dementsprechend oftmals schwer etymologisch aufzuschlüsseln.

Gefühlt würde ich sagen, dass sich 'eine' auf 'eine Ohrfeige' bezog, die vom Sprachgefühl eventuell älter, weiter verbreitet und weniger vulgär ist als andere (interessanterweise auch feminine) Optionen wie 'Backpfeife', 'Schelle', 'Fotzen', 'Watschen'.

Zudem möchte ich meinen, dass das 'Kleben' von dem Bild des Klebens von beispielsweise Stickern oder Plakaten kommt, die man auch oft mit der offenen Hand auf Hefte, Gegenstände oder ähnliches kleben kann und den Bewegungsabläufen einer Ohrfeige sehr nahe kommt.

Die Informationen hierzu sind aber begrenzt:
[link1](https://www.redensarten-index.de/suche.php?suchbegriff=~~jemandem%20eine%20%2F%20ein%20paar%20kleben&bool=relevanz&suchspalte%5B%5D=rart_ou)
[link2](https://de.etc.sprache.deutsch.narkive.com/gRlhhzSw/f-herkunft-jmd-eine-kleben)

Answer (score 4):

Die Website [Redensarten-Index](https://www.redensarten-index.de/suche.php?suchbegriff=~~jemandem%20eine%20kleben&bool=relevanz&gawoe=an&suchspalte[]=rart_ou&suchspalte[]=rart_varianten_ou) gibt an, dass sich diese umgangssprachliche Redewendung

> "wahrscheinlich auf den Schlag, mit dem man eine Klebefläche (etwa einer Briefmarke) auf dem Untergrund befestigt [bezieht]."

Comment: Interessant! Das würde bedeuten, dass der Ausdruck relativ neu ist.

Comment: "umgangssprachlich; Diese seit dem 19. Jahrhundert bekannte Redensart bezieht sich wahrscheinlich auf den Schlag, mit dem man eine Klebefläche (etwa einer Briefmarke) auf dem Untergrund befestigt "
Super, diese Erklärung! Darum hat man mir wohl immer gesagt: "Jetzt  bist du gerade so flach herausgekommen wie eine Briefmarke, nur nicht so zackig!"

Comment: Klingt gut, aber warum sollte ich jemanden eine Briefmarke ankleben, (anschlagen). Irgendwie fehlt da vlt. noch was in der Erklärung?!
@AlbrechtHügli: Klar man kann geistig so flach sein, wie eine Briefmarke, aber deshalb klebe ich sie dir nicht auf, oder ich markiere dich als flach?!

Comment: und dann noch eins mit dem Stempel drauf! Wenn du meine Deutung verfolgst, wirst du sehen, dass ich nicht auf die Briefmarke gekommen bin, sondern aus obigem  zitiere. Ich kenne das nur von einer Wasche, was ja hier arg bezweifelt wird - wobei  mir der Zusammenhang mit waschen etwas an den Haaren herbeigezogen schein.  Aber da man in ganz Europa "eine klebt", finde ich den Hinweis auf das Kleben einer  Briefmarken einleuchtend. In der Bibel steht jedenfalls noch nichts davon, aber das  Markieren von Rindviechern im wilden Westen ist schon ein älterer Brauch. Und so komme ich mir hier auch vor!

Comment: @Albrecht-Hügli *Wasche* scheint offensichtlich eine Abwandlung von *Watsche(n)*, vgl. vielleicht En. "swat" (fly swatter - Fliegenklatsche). Oder etwa "eine wischen", vgl. *sweep*.

Comment: klar, vectory, da liegst du vollkommen richtig: so wie waschen an sich und also auch das Verb überhaupt von plitschen und platschen kommt: da werden die Kleider auf eine Brett geklatscht, und da wird geknatscht und getratscht! schau mal nach was Iris Busch alles über die Waschweiber weiss: https://www.grin.com/document/60810

Answer (score 1):

Zur Frage der regionalen Bekanntheit: "jemand**em** eine kleben" ist zumindest in Berlin durchaus geläufig. Andere hier gebräuchliche Ausdrücke mit gleicher Bedeutung wären: jmd. eine knallen, eine scheuern. "Eine 'runterhauen" wird zwar oft ebenfalls mit der Bedeutung "eine Ohrfeige/Backpfeife verpassen" benutzt, *kann* allerdings auch einen heftigeren Schlag meinen.

P.S.
Da hier in einigen Antworten nebenbei auch auf die Bezeichnung für den verabreichten Schlag eingegangen wurde: Watsche(n) oder Schelle würde "hierzulande" zwar verstanden, aber nicht benutzt werden. Dafür ist mir als weiteren Name noch der "Katzenkopf" eingefallen.

Comment: Die Beugung von *jemand* kann man auch weglassen ([habe ich hier gelernt](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/2417/how-do-i-decline-jemand-or-niemand))

Comment: @Takkat aber man muss auch nicht alles tun, was man (theoretisch) darf :Augenroll: - bei gewissen Dingen, die der Duden in letzter Zeit erlaubt, rollen sich bei mir (Jahrgang 1968) die Zehnägel hoch.

Comment: Duden ist diesmal unschuldig, die ungebeugte Form soll auf Mittelhochdeutsch zurück gehen, erst in der Neuzeit habe man die Beugung eingeführt, sagt [diese Antwort](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/15814/23). Auch meine Zehennägel wollen manchmal nicht mehr in die Schuhe passen (Jg. 1961).

Answer (score -1):

*jemand eine kleben*

Damit ist ganz klar gemeint: **jemandem eine Watsche (Ohrfeige) kleben.**

(bei uns in der Schweiz heisst es zwar "eine Wasche" )

https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Watsche

[image]

Das **Kleben** rührt sicher daher, dass man auf der 
Wange noch lange den Hände Abdruck des Lehrers kleben sehen konnte.

(Der Grund für kleben könnte auch sein, dass sich *kleben* so schön reimt auf *geben.*

Dafür gibt es im Duden zwar  keinen Beleg, aber bei mir jedenfalls war das immer so,
und ich kann dir sagen, ich habe in meiner Schulzeit manche Ohrfeigen kassiert.
Das sollte eigentlich als statistischer Beweis genügen!

**(Das war nicht einfach Spass und auch nicht anekdotisch gemeint!)**

[image]

wobei mir in diesem Beleg besonders die Formulierung **im raum- zeitlichen Zusammenhang am Herzen liegt - um nicht zu sagen "klebt"**

Für mich ist es so gut erwiesen, dass auch Watsche und Wasche aus einer Laut- malerischen Bildung von dem Geräusch "durchs Wasser waten" kommt. (s. **witsch, watsch, wutsch, wie plitsch, platsch, oder klipp, klapp). Bei klapp oder klap** möchte ich noch darauf hinweisen, dass ein Klaps (oder ein Chlaps) ebenfalls für eine runterhauen steht. Dass bei Klaps das dabei entstehende Geräusch gemeint ist, muss ich wohl nicht mit Grimm und Duden belegen. Und jetzt klopf, klopf, klopf, dämmert vielleicht bei einigen endlich etwas: kleben hat nämlich nichts mit Briefmarken zu tun, sondern ist wie klopfen und klatschen und watschen und patschen und stampfen (ach ja, Briefmarken werden gestempelt) ... **kleben ist auch Lautmalerei**. Leider steht das nirgendwo bei Grimm, aber hätte ich damals gelebt und Grimm hätte mich gefragt, dann hätte ich es ihm erklärt und Grimm hätte das sicher eingeleuchtet. Er hätte dann geschrieben:

**"Kleben kommt von dem Geräusch, das entsteht, wenn man die Planken eines Bootes mit Pech und Fisch Kleister aneinander klebt. Das hat schon zu Noahs Zeiten beim Bau der Arche so getönt. Beim Kleben musste man nämlich mit der flachen Hand auf die Bretter schlagen und sie zusammen binden bis sie trocken waren."** (zitiert nach Albrecht Hügli, der am Wohlensee aufgewachsen ist und in seiner frühen Jugend selber noch die Planken der  Fischerboote kleben und flicken musste).

Es ist für mich so gut wie erwiesen, dass auch Watsche und Wasche aus einer Laut- malerischen Bildung von dem Geräusch "durchs Wasser waten" kommt. (s. witsch, watsch, wutsch, wie plitsch, platsch, oder klipp, klapp). Bei klapp oder klap möchte ich noch darauf hinweisen, dass ein Klaps (oder ein Chlaps) ebenfalls für eine runterhauen steht. Dass bei Klaps das dabei entstehende Geräusch gemeint ist, muss ich wohl nicht mit Grimm und Duden belegen. Und jetzt klopf, klopf, klopf, dämmert vielleicht bei einigen endlich etwas:  "eine kleben" hat nämlich ursprünglich nichts mit Briefmarken zu tun, sondern "kleben" ist wie klopfen und klatschen und watschen und patschen und stampfen (ach ja, Briefmarken werden gestempfelt): **"kleben" ist auch Lautmalerei und ist verwandt mit chläpfen.** Leider steht das nirgendwo bei Grimm, aber hätte ich damals gelebt und Grimm hätte mich gefragt, dann hätte ich es ihm erklärt und Grimm hätte das sicher eingeleuchtet. Er hätte dann geschrieben:

"Kleben kommt von dem Geräusch, das entsteht, wenn man mit Pech und Fisch- Kleister  die Planken eines Bootes zusammenleimt. Beim Kleben musste man nämlich mit der flachen Hand auf die Bretter schlagen und sie zusammenbinden, bis sie trocken waren. Kleben hiess darum klepen oder auf grindelwaldnerisch kläpen und kommt  von kleppen, wie auch ein Klepper mit seinen Hufen auf dem Strassenflasters davon kleppert! (vgl auch Kläpfen oder Klaps, welcher Ausdruck einen Schlag auf den Hintern oder sonst irgend eine Backe nachahmt.) *zitiert nach Albrecht Hügli, welchjeniger seinerzeit am Wohlensee aufgewachsen ist und schon damals in seiner frühen Jugend selber noch an Fischerbooten die Planken kleben und flicken zuschauen/helfen durfte.*

Ich habe schon in der ersten Klasse von der Lehrerin einen Chlapf bzw. eine Wasche geleimt bekommen, weil ich meinte, man müsse beim Leimen und Kleben von Sonntagsschulbildchen mit der Hand auf den Heiland klopfen, damit er fest geheftet bleibt. Dass sowas nicht geht, wurde mir dabei sofort klipp und klap ähm, klar mitgeteilt beziehungsweise eingebrannt!

Und jetzt dürft ihr mal raten, woher der Begriff "Waschweiber" kommt!

Oh, ihr wollt es wirklich wissen, na, dann los:

https://www.grin.com/document/60810

und was sagt der Duden? kurz: blabla!

Schwätzer, Schwätzerin; Plauderer, Plauderin; (abwertend) Fabulant, Fabulantin, Phrasendrescher, Phrasendrescherin, Wortemacher, Wortemacherin; (umgangssprachlich scherzhaft) Plaudertasche; (umgangssprachlich abwertend) Faseler, Faselerin, Klatschbase, Klatsche, Klatschtante, Klatschtrine, Klatschweib, Labertasche, Plapperer, Plapperin, Plappermaul, Plappertasche, Quasselfritze, Quasseltante, Quasselkopf, Salbader, Schnatterer, Schnatterin, Schnattergans, Schnatterliese, Schwafler, Schwaflerin, Schwatzbase; (salopp abwertend) Klatschmaul, Quasselstrippe, Quatschkopf; (umgangssprachlich veraltend abwertend) Faselhans; (bildungssprachlich veraltet) Phraseur; (landschaftlich umgangssprachlich) Quackeler, Quackelerin; (Jugendsprache abwertend) Schwaller, Schwallerin; (veraltend) Schwadroneur

**und ich lasse mir hier von keinem mehr sagen, warum fragst du, wenn du es doch selber weisst? oder bist du zu faul zum googlen?**

Comment: Anekdotische Beweise haben leider keinen Wert/Gültigkeit. Ich sehe nicht den Sinn von Spekulationen an dieser Stelle, du schreibst ja selbst, es gibt keinen Beleg dafür.

Comment: Leider ist diese Antwort wirklich völlig ohne (gutes) Argument. Daher gebe ich hier -1.

Comment: Und du glaubst tatsächlich, weil irgend ein anderer etwas in einem Buch aufgeschrieben hat, dass dies dann wahr ist? Für mich sind das alles bloss alternative Fakten! „ Eine kleben“ ist bestimmt schon älter als dass man angefangen hat Briefmarken aufzukleben ... sieh mal meinen Kommentar dort. Ich kann natürlich im Internet eine Seite über Redensarten eröffnen. Du darfst dich dann gerne darauf beziehen.

Comment: Ich kenne nur "jemandem eine Watsche (oder Ohrfeige) geben" oder "jemanden eine kleben". Die Kombination "jemandem eine Watsche (oder Ohrfeige) **kleben**" gibt es nicht.

Comment: (bei uns heisst es zwar Wasche ... ) Wasche oder Watsche?

Comment: hier heisst es: eine Wasche! Watsche ist bayrisch. Es könnte sein, dass das tatsächlich  mit waschen zusammenhängt.  Es wird nämlich auch gesagt: Du bist wohl heute noch nicht gewaschen worden?! (Da stell ich mir schon einen Waschlappen vor - oder eine kalte Dusche!

Comment: Ich zitiere  ja selbest: "was man schwarz auf weiss besitzt kann man getrost mit nach Hause tragen ... und damit meine ich eure Überheblichkeit und eure Fehleinschätzung, zu meinen, weil etwas in einem Duden oder in einem Buch steht, sei das die richtige Interpretation und Auslegung von einer Aussage und ihrer Bedeutung. Was bleibt mir anderes übrig als euch mit euren eigenen Argumenten zu schlagen, wenn  eigene Gedanken und Überlegungen nichts gelten? Hier haben offensichtlich gewisse Leute die Deutungshoheit gepachtet, was diese SE soll, wie  fragen, wie antworten, in  welcher  Formatierung.

Comment: Ich kann ja auch googeln, wenn es sein muss:
https://books.google.ch/books?id=A-vpBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA26&lpg=PA26&dq=eine+watsche+kleben&source=bl&ots=zK5myqDh3O&sig=ACfU3U3XAXbSZxOQIUiRSgC-qaH2i21zNQ&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj_ypbgwZXgAhURtXEKHfZ3B3kQ6AEwAnoECAEQAQ#v=onepage&q=eine%20watsche%20kleben&f=false
und wie es euch gefällt.
Da steht doch auf S. 26:"... etwas anderes als das Kleben der Hand an einer Backe." also bin ich wohl nicht der einzige.

Comment: aber weisst du was, Iris: I habe gerade vor einem Monat  zum ersten Mal etwas von SE gehört, als ich nach Chopins Etuden  Op. 10, 1 gegoogelt habe. Ich war tief beeindruckt über die Art, wie da einander geholfen wird (insbesondere Anfängern und fremdsprachigen Menschen gegenüber) und wie freundlich der Umgangston ist.  Ich wollte schon in der Meta fragen, wo und wie man sich bedanken könne für die Hilfe der Admins und Mods. 
In anderen Foren sind noch viel mehr Inder, Pakistani, Afrikaner, die nicht richtig englisch können ...

Comment: Die Referenz aus Schiemanns Synonymwörterbuch ist sehr interessant! Kannst du hier ([edit]) noch eine Zusammenfassung der wesentlichen Punkte einfügen, damit deine Antwort noch Wert hat, wenn Google die Seitenkopien wieder entfernt?

Comment: siehst, Takkat, das ist was ich gemeint habe, was bei einigen wohl als Polemik rübergekommen ist: wenn es Schiemann gesagt hat, ist es interessant, wenn es Albrecht Hügli sagt, ist es non-sens. :)

Comment: *Der Grund für kleben könnte auch sein, dass sich kleben so schön reimt auf geben* Das hat der Hügli gesagt und das ist weit weniger unfug als der Rest.

Comment: Ich war wirklich verwirrt, weil du "bei uns heisst es zwar Wasche ..." schreibst und dann direkt darunter eine Quelle zu "Watsche" angibst, wo steht " Gebrauch: bayrisch, österreichisch umgangssprachlich". Woher soll jemand der nicht deine anderen Antworten verfolgt wissen, dass "bei uns" die Schweiz meint (tut es doch, oder?) und warum dann der Link auf eine Quelle in der "Wasche" nicht erwähnt wird? "Kleben" wird im Duden übrigens auch nicht erwähnt.

Comment: isch notiert! Ich habe den Text editiert. Ediert oder editiert, das war auch mal so eine Frage! Unser Deutschlehrer war nämlich der Präsident des Bernischen Schriftsteller Verbandes ... und damals war übrigens der Trend, alles klein und zusammen zu schreiben.

Comment: Also ehrlich gesagt ist mir mit den vielen Revisionen Deine an und für sich gar nicht so schlechte Antwort jetzt zu unübersichtlich und durcheinander geraten. Ich glaube da ist mittlerweile zu  viel hineingeraten, manches auch doppelt. Reine Textauszüge sollten grundsätzlich bitte nicht als Screenshot eingebunden werden, man kann sonst nicht darin suchen und für Leute an einer langsamen Netzanbindung oder am Smartphone sind solche "Bilder" nutzlos bis ärgerlich.

Comment: @ Takkat: da hast du vollkommen recht! An letztere user habe ich leider nicht gedacht. Ich glaube, das beste ist wohl ich lösche das ganze. O.K.?  Danke übrigens für die Note "nicht so schlecht" ;) Ich habe immer gesagt: "Eine 4 ist immer noch die beste Ungenügende!"

Comment: @AlbrechtHügli: ich finde eine kurze Erwähnung von Wa(t)sche gut und von Schiemanns Artikel muss ein Auszug als Beleg dienen, damit klar ist, dass es nicht nur Albrecht ist, der das meint. Alles was nicht direkt mit der Frage zu tun hat sollte aber noch gekürzt werden... dann wird eine schöne Antwort draus!

Comment: Ich kopier dann das ganze mal für mich als ein schönes Souvenir ;)

Answer (score -1):

Das ganze ist offensichtlich (sprich, Ich habe dafür keinen Beleg) verwandt mit En. *clap* und damit gleichbedeutend mit *klatschen*.

Man sagt auch, "das klappt nicht" (that won't work), das mit En. *glue* (kleben) verwandt sein dürfte im Sinne *das wird nicht halten, nicht richtig abschließen*.

Vgl. auch *Kloppe*, *klopfen*, En. *hard knocks*.

Am Rande: Man könnte denken, *eine scheuern* sei nur in Anlehnung der von anderen erwähnten "Waschen", bzw. "Watschen" entstanden, doch könnte *scheuern*, wenn mich nicht alles täuscht, auf PIE *skew- (vgl. to shut, schützen, schießen, Haus) zurückgehen und, insofern sinngemäße Vergleichbarkeit mit *klappen* vorliegt, eine Bedeutung ca. *drehen, schwingen* suggerieren, da eine klappende klappe gedreht wird, bzw. der *Scheuerlappen* geschwungen wird. So heißt ein Leberhaken auch *Schwinger* ... und "in der Drehe" bedeutet *in der Wohngegend* oder einfach *ca*. Man sagt auch "das hat gezwirbelt", vgl. En. *twirl*.

Comment: Vgl. Schwäbisch *heben* (für halten, funktionieren...).