# Dativ von „jemand anderes“ – „jemandem anderen“ oder „jemand anderem“?

Tags: grammar, dative, accusative

Wie wird am geläufigsten der Dativ und der Akkusativ von „jemand anderes“ gebildet? Gibt es ein Prinzip, nach welchem hier die Objektfälle gebildet werden, und wie lässt sich diese Frage grammatikalisch analysieren?

Möglichkeiten, die ich gesehen habe (nach Verweis auf Duden durch hek2mgl):

> 1. Ich schlage *jemanden anderen*.
> 2. Ich schlage *jemanden anderes*.
> 3. Ich schlage *jemand anderen*.
> 4. Ich schlage *jemand anders*.

Ich persönlich würde (1) bilden.

Verwandt ist die Frage, [ob man „niemand“ und „jemand“ überhaupt beugen soll](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/723/beugt-man-jemand-oder-niemand-mit-endung).

**Nachtrag**: Um die Frage noch mal deutlicher zu machen, möchte ich betonen, dass es mir um **die Beugung von „jemand“ und „anders“** geht, wenn die beiden Wörter **kombiniert als „jemand anders“ bzw. „jemand anderer“** auftreten.
Das Gewicht liegt auch auf der zweiten Frage, welche anders gewendet lautet: Wie fungieren hier „jemand“ und „anders“ grammatikalisch?

Answer (score 5):

Laut [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/jemand) ist beides möglich: *jemandem* oder *jemand*. Ich bevorzuge in deinem Beispiel *jemand:*

> Ich schlage jemand anderem vor, mich mit ihm zu treffen.
>
> Ich schlage jemand anderem in den Bauch.  [nur ein Beispiel]

Ich hab die Sache mal an eine Ex-Deutschlehrerin weitergeleitet, wie versprochen.

Antwort:

> " niemand" u. "jemand" sollte man schon deklinieren, besonders im  Dativ u. Akkusativ , Die Verbindung "jemand anders" ist laut Duden am häufigsten indeklinabel gebräuchlich, aber es ist  auch legitim, "anderes" zu beugen, wobei "jemand" ungebeugt bleibt, z.B.: "mit jemand anderem".
>
> Es stellt sich allerdings die Frage, ob die Konstruktion semantisch sinnvoll ist.