# »Von jemand anderen« oder »von jemand anderem«?

Tags: grammatical-case, indefinite-pronoun

Auf Facebook bin ich gerade auf eine Frage gestoßen, die ich nicht eindeutig beantworten konnte. Sie lautet:

> Was ist richtig?
>
> 1. *»anderer«* nach *»von jemand«* im Dativ:
>
>    Das ist die Sache von jemand **anderem.**
>      Von jemand **anderem** würde ich das annehmen.
> 2. *»anderer«* nach *»von jemand«* im Akkusativ:
>
>    Das ist die Sache von jemand **anderen.**
>      Von jemand **anderen** würde ich das annehmen.

Wenn man *»jemand«* durch *»niemand«* ersetzt (beides sind  Indefinitpronomen), scheint (1) die richtige Lösung zu sein:

> 1. Von niemand **anderem** würde ich das annehmen.
> 2. <del>Von niemand **anderen** würde ich das annehmen.</del>

Ein anderes Indefinitpronomen ist *»ein«*. Setzt man dieses Wort ein, kommt, wie ich glaube, aber nur (2) in Frage:

> 1. <del>Von einem **anderem** würde ich das annehmen.</del>
> 2. Von einem **anderen** würde ich das annehmen.

**Meine Fragen:**

- Wie ist das im Fall von *»jemand«*?
- Warum unterscheiden sich *»niemand«* und *»ein«*?
- Im Dativ können anstelle von *»jemand«* und *»niemand«* auch *»jemand**em**«* und *»niemand**em**«* verwendet werden. Hat das Einfluss darauf, ob das nachfolgende Indefinitpronomen *»anders«* im Dativ oder im Akkusativ zu verwenden ist?

Comment: Related: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/6777/dativ-von-jemand-anderes-jemandem-anderen-oder-jemand-anderem

Answer (score 2):

*jemand* und *niemand* sind **Indefinitpronomen** und damit stehen sie für ein Nomen im Satz. Sie können sowohl in der flektierten als auch unflektierten Form auftauchen. Sie werden wie jedes Pronomen flektiert.

*andere* ist ebenfalls ein **Indefinitpronomen** und steht ebenfalls für ein Nomen im Satz, und wird ebenfalls flektiert.

**Aber**: *ander[e]s gibt es auch als *Adverb*, das das Indefinitpronomen näher attributiert. Und das Adverb wird normalerweise **nicht** flektiert. **nochmal Aber**: [Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/anders) sagt, das Adverb *anders* würde im südlichen deutschen Sprachraum **eben doch** flektiert (war mir auch neu). Canoo ist anderer Ansicht und hält das Adverb *anders* für unflektierbar, sagt aber, wenn es flektiert wird, ist es ein Indefinitpronomen (?!).

*jemand anderes* ist also eine Aneinanderreihung von Indefinitpronomen und Adverb, das "gesamtdeutsch" laut [Canoo](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/InflectionRules/FRegeln-P/Pron-Indef/Pron-andere3.html#Anchor-jemand-3800) so zu flektieren ist:

- jemand anders (N)

  - <s>jemandes anders</s> jemandes anderen (G, Sonderfall)
- jemandem anders (D)
- jemanden anders (A)

(Ich glaub's mal, ich rede nicht so, sondern eher so wie du, für mich hört sich das falsch an)

Die Formen, in denen in bestimmten Fällen stattdessen "anders" anstatt "jemand" flektiert wird, halten sowohl Duden als auch Canoo für spezifisch süddeutsch, aber nicht falsch. Deine und meine Verwirrung stammen also aus einer Mischung aus Hochsprache und akzeptierter Regionalsprache und wir haben hiermit aufgrund unserer Herkunft aus dem süddeutschen Sprachraum einen "grammatischen Jagdschein".

Comment: Danke fürs Recherchieren, aber das beantwortet meine Frage nicht ganz. *»Das ist die Sache von jemand **anders.**«* habe ich zwar schon gehört (in der Steiermark, nicht in Wien), ist aber sicher nicht Standarddeutsch und war nicht Gegenstand meiner Frage. Das gilt auch für *»Von jemand **anders** würde ich das annehmen.«* Ich habe versucht, den Kern meiner Frage im Titel zusammenzufassen: »**von jemand anderen/m**«. Es geht mir darum, ob das letzte Wort in Dativ (*andere**m***) oder im Akkusativ (*andere**n***)  stehen muss. Von *»ander**s**«* war nie die Rede.

Comment: Du hast die Antwort nicht richtig gelesen. "*Von jemand anderem/n*" existiert für die "gesamtdeutsche" hochdeutsche Grammatik nicht. Das heißt, zumindestens nach den von mir konsultierten Grammatiken, *von jemand(em) anderes*. Daher erübrigt sich deine Frage, bzw. die Antwort lautet "keins von beidem"

Comment: Willst du damit sagen, die beiden folgenden Sätze wären korrekt: *»Das ist die Sache **von jemand anders. Von jemand anders** würde ich das annehmen.«*? Ebenso: *»**Von niemand anders** würde ich das annehmen.«* und *»**Von einem anders** würde ich das annehmen.«* Insbesondere beim letzten Beispiel regt sich bei mir der Wunsch heftig zu widersprechen.

Comment: Deine Sätze mit "jemand(em)"/"niemand(em)" entsprechen dem, was ich in den Grammatiken gefunden habe, und sollten daher richtig sein, auch wenn sie nicht unbedingt meinem "süddeutschen" Sprachgefühl entsprechen würden. Der letzte Satz ist für mich auch eindeutig falsch, das ist aber auch "was anderes"

Comment: Das "was anderes" ist für mich ein substantivischer Gebrauch des indefinitpronomens, "ein anderer" würde ich gerne großschreiben, darf aber nicht.