# »jemand(em) schreiben« vs. »an jemand(en) schreiben«

Tags: difference, preposition, grammatical-case

Was ist der Unterschied zwischen *jemand(em) schreiben* und *an jemand(en) schreiben?*

Es kommt mir so vor, dass *jemand(em) schreiben* gebräuchlicher ist, also Dativ. Wird der Dativ immer bevorzugt und klingt irgendwie besser? Gibt es beispielsweise wirklich keinen Unterschied zwischen den folgenden Sätzen?

> Ich kann ihm eine Mail schreiben.
>
> Ich kann an ihn eine Mail schreiben.

Comment: warum schreibst du die Beugung zwischen Klammern?

Comment: Da laut canoo.net Beides Richtig ist.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Man kann grundsätzlich sowohl „jemandem schreiben“ als auch „an jemanden schreiben“ sagen. Im Duden – *Deutsches Universalwörterbuch* stehen für das Verb *schreiben* mit der Bedeutung „eine schriftliche Nachricht senden; sich schriftlich an jemanden wenden“ gleich als erste Beispiele

> du hast deinen Eltern lange nicht geschrieben
>   du hast an deine Eltern lange nicht geschrieben

In Duden – *Richtiges und gutes Deutsch* wird erklärt, dass die Konstruktion mit *an* hervorhebt, dass man sich in einer bestimmten Angelegenheit an einen Adressaten (z. B. an eine Behörde oder öffentliche Stelle) wendet. Hierzu findet man im Duden – *Stilwörterbuch* das Beispiel

> er hat an das Finanzamt [einen Beschwerdebrief] geschrieben

Ebenda findet man auch ein Beispiel für den umgekehrten Fall, dass die Konstruktion ohne *an* bevorzugt wird:

> sie hat mir [einen Brief] geschrieben

Weitere Konstruktionen ohne *an* sind erweiterte Ausdrücke wie „jemandem [etwas] über jemanden/etwas schreiben“ oder „jemandem [etwas] von jemandem/etwas schreiben“.

> sie hat mir nur wenig von dir geschrieben
>   sie hat mir nur wenig von der Sache geschrieben
>   er schrieb mir über dich
>   er schrieb mir über deine Pläne

Comment: M.M.n. kann man also praktisch schließen, dass der Satz mit dem "an" eher förmlicher ist.

Answer (score 5):

Ich finde beide Varianten *fast* gleichwertig.

Für den Sonderfall eines Textes, der zwar als Brief (oder sonstiges Schreiben) an jemanden konzipiert ist, aber nicht wirklich an diesen geschickt werden soll, tendiert mein Sprachgefühl (habe bislang leider keine bessere Referenz) klar zur Version mit "an". D.h. ich glaube, Kafka hätte gesagt "Ich schreibe einen [Brief an meinen Vater](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brief_an_den_Vater)", und nicht "Ich schreibe meinem Vater".

Ansonsten finde ich, ähnlich wie Loong in seiner Antwort, daß die Version mit "an" üblicher ist, wenn der Adressat eine Institution ist, und die Version mit Dativ, wenn es sich um eine Person handelt. Man kann sogar mit dieser Nuance spielen:

> Ich schreibe dem Finanzamt.

Dieser Satz klingt ein wenig so, als ob der Sprecher sich das Finanzamt wie eine konkrete Person vorstellt.

Zur der hier am Rande berührten Frage, ob man *jemand* oder *jemandem* schreibt, gibt es Antworten in [Beugt man jemand oder niemand mit Endung?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/723/beugt-man-jemand-oder-niemand-mit-endung)

Answer (score 1):

Beide Formen sind gleichwertig und werden in allen gängigen Nachschlagewerken nebeneinander geführt.

Answer (score 0):

M.E. ist die Erklärung am Anfang zutreffend. Beides ist korrekt, aber 'an' hat einen etwas formellen Charakter. Entsprechend passt es auch das Kafka einen "Brief an den Vater schreibt" (das Verhältnis der beiden ist auch eher formell/steif), während ich meiner Schwester einfach mal so "einen Brief schreib".

Comment: Willkommen bei German.SE. Heißt das in Konsequenz, dass der Dativ für informelle Ausdrücke gebraucht wird und sonst z.B. auf den Akkusativ zurückgegriffen wird? Ich fand in einer anderen Antwort mal diesen Link, dort wird bei "an" das nun nicht thematisiert. https://www.deutschplus.net/pages/Wechselprapositionen