# Dativ bei den Verben "herumhacken" und "herumreiten"

Tags: grammatical-case

Warum sagt man

> auf jemande**m** rumhacken/rumreiten

wo die Verben doch der Umgangssprache angehören? Ich gehe davon aus, dass die Kombination "auf + Dativ" eher für schriftliche Texte üblich ist bzw. etwas veraltet ist /lasten auf, fußen auf, beruhen auf usw./

Comment: Ich verstehe die Frage nicht. Denkst Du, dass die Umgangssprache keinen Dativ kennt?

Comment: Was veranlasst dich zu der Annahme? Dafür gibt es keinen Grund. Du solltest auch nicht nach Verben suchen, sondern nach *Präpositionen* - Die regieren den Kasus, wenn sie vorhanden sind.

Comment: @tofro Das ist richtig, hilft aber bei Propositionen wie "auf",
die mit Dativ oder Akkusativ gebraucht werden, nicht unbedingt weiter.
Man muß sich dann schon merken, daß "herumhacken" mit "auf" + Dativ
gebraucht wird, "einhacken" aber mit "auf" + Akkusativ.

Comment: Man sagt [auf jemand herumhacken](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/723/beugt-man-jemand-oder-niemand-mit-endung), (also ohne Beugung) und auf **etwas** herumreiten.

Comment: @Uwe Doch, das hilft - Man lernt zumindestens, dass da Dativ oder Akkusativ stehen kann.

Comment: @Tackat. Dass man das Suffix "verschluckt" (= nicht ausspricht), heißt nicht, dass es in der im Hirn gespeicherten grammatischen Struktur nicht vorhanden wäre. Ausnotiert könnte man so schreiben: "Auf jemand(em) herumhacken." Anders gesagt: Der Dativ ist durchaus vorhanden, er verliert nur seine physische Ausprägung. Sprachwissenschaftler sprechen dann bekanntlich gerne auch von Null-Suffixen (jemand-ø), also Suffixen, die "unsichtbar" sind, aber dennoch Bedeutung tragen.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann: genau deswegen auch nur ein Kommentar ;)

Comment: Der Dativ hat m. E. mit den genannten Verben nichts zu tun sondern ergibt sich aus der Verwendung von *auf* bei einer Ortsangabe; vergleiche *auf dem Stuhl sitzen*, *auf der Agenda stehen*.

Comment: @Tackat   Man sagt auch *auf wem rumhacken* und *auf was rumreiten*. (Wenn schon Alltagssprache, dann denn schon!) Aber da isser wieder, der Dativ, samt seinem ihm ureignen -m.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann: das und auch Deine Antwort sind völlig korrekt, erklären aber nicht, warum oben der Dativ stehen muss und hier der Akkusativ: *auf jemand einreden*. Ich finde, genau diese interessante Frage hätte zumindest einen Antwortversuch verdient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deine Frage hat mit Umgangssprache, Schriftlichkeit oder Schriftsprache überhaupt nichts zu tun. Dativ und Akkusativ sind sowohl in der Schrift- als auch der Umgangssprache beide gleich geläufig.

Wenn in einem deutschen Satz eine Präposition vorhanden ist, regiert sie im Allgemeinen vorrangig den Kasus (das Verb ist dann nur in zweiter Linier relevant).

"auf" kann sowohl den Akkusativ als auch den Dativ regieren - Dabei kommt eine zweite Regel für die Wahl des Kasus zum Tragen:

Bei Bewegungen "auf etwas zu" steht normalerweise der Akkusativ, bei (relativem) Stillstand steht der Dativ:

> Der Mann springt auf den Bus auf

(Akkusativ, klar eine Bewegung auf etwas zu)

> Die Menge tanzt auf dem Marktplatz

(relativer Stillstand, die Menge bewegt sich zwar, verläßt den Marktplatz aber nicht, daher Dativ)

Nehmen wir nun deinen Beispielsatz

> auf jemand(em)/etwas herumhacken

so bleibt der "Täter" statisch am "Tatort" - es findet keinerlei Bewegung "auf etwas zu" statt, daher steht kein Akkusativ, sondern Dativ.

Ein anderes Beispiel für Akkusativ aus den Kommentaren zu deiner Frage:

> auf jemand(en) einreden

Hier bewegt sich die "Rede" sozusagen auf den "Jemand" zu (zu den Endungen in Klammern siehe Kommentare, sie sind nicht wirklich notwendig, verdeutlichen hier aber den Kasus), daher Akkusativ.

Answer (score -1):

Die Wendung *auf jemandem herumhacken* wird nun einmal traditionell mit Dativ gebildet.

Dass in der Alltagssprache Faul- und Schludrigkeit ihr Revier haben, ist ja ein bekanntes Phänomen. So werden Suffixe (Endsilben, die grammatische Bedeutung tragen) auch oft mal verschluckt (= nicht ausgesprochen). Dies heißt aber nicht, dass der Kasus Dativ deswegen weg wäre. Im Kopf des Sprechers (und des Hörers) ist er trotzdem noch vorhanden.

Schau mal hier:

> 1) Auf jemandem herumhacken
>
> 2) Auf jemand-ø rumhacken
>
> 3) Auf wem rumhacken

(1) gibt die schriftsprachlich korrekte und morphologisch vollständige Form wieder. In (2) hat der Sprecher die Dativ-Endung von *jemand**em*** verschluckt (und nebenbei noch das *he* von *herum*, aber das sei uns hier egal). Trotzdem hat er den Dativ noch im Kopf (was ich hier mit dem Zeichen ø für ein "Nullmorphem" ausdrücke). Wie kann ich da so sicher sein? Weil derselbe Sprecher in (3) auf einmal wieder eine Dativ-Form (*wem*) verwendet, obwohl er hier noch kürzer und grammatisch "unkorrekter" geworden ist mit der Verwendung des Fragewörtchens *wem* als Pronomen.

Der Kerl kann noch so schludern - den Dativ kriegt er nicht aus dem Kopf.

Comment: Sowohl im Akkusativ als im Dativ wird die unflektierte Form der Indefinitpronomen "jemand"/"niemand" schon seit langem (auch in der Schriftsprache) als "richtig" anerkannt und steht gleichberechtigt daneben. Von "Alltagssprache" oder "schlampiger Sprache" kann also nicht die Rede sein. Es ist ganz einfach sowohl "jemand" als auch "jemandem" richtig. Nur der Genitiv muss sichtbar flektiert werden.

Comment: ... Selbst der Grimm tadelt die Endung "jemand**em**" als "neumodische Unsitte": http://woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GJ00786#XGJ00786