# niemandem Rechenschaft abzulegen haben

Tags: sentence-structure

> Seine Haltung ist die eines Mannes, der niemandem Rechenschaft abzulegen hat.

Shouldn't it be "niemanden"? And why *abzulegen* in here? Shouldn't it be the perfect?

Comment: Related: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/723/beugt-man-jemand-oder-niemand-mit-endung - if in doubt just say *niemand* ;)

Comment: @Takkat Ich glaube, dass es hier eher darum geht, warum "niemand" im Dativ und nicht im Akkusativ steht.

Comment: @Martin ja genau, das hast du völlig richtig erkannt. Genau darum geht es.

Comment: Wem?: niemandem. Wen/was?: Rechenschaft  -> da sind sie wieder die 2 Objektarten

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be: "Seine Haltung ist die eines Mannes, ..." Because "Haltung" is female and die refers to it. "Niemandem" is correct, because you ask "wem gegenüber Rechenschaft ablegen?".

Comment: thanks indeed ... one more question please .. why abzulegen? why not abgelegt?

Comment: With *abgelegt hat* the meaning would be that the man never accounted to anybody. But the original sentence says that he never has to account to anybody.

Comment: *Hat zu* is a direct cognate to English *have to* = *must*.

Comment: Der Teil »weil man fragt "wem gegenüber ..."« hilft jemanden, der Deutsch lernt genau gar nicht weiter. Dass man hier nach dem Dativ fragen muss ist jemanden, der gerade erst Deutsch lernt, genauso unklar wie die Tatsache, dass man hier einen Dativ verwenden muss. Stattdessen wäre es hilfreich zu erklären, warum hier die Frage nach dem Dativ angebracht ist.

Comment: @Janka: »weil er niemandem Rechenschaft abgelegt **hat**« - Wie übersetzt du das mit *»have to = must«*? Der Fragesteller hat ja nicht nach dem Hilfsverb gefragt, sonder nach dem Perfekt (*hat abgelegt*) anstelle von des vorhandenen Infinitvs mit zu und Hilfsverb (*abzulegen hat*).

Comment: *Er **hat** ab**zu**legen.* folgt demselben Muster wie *Er **hat zu** verstehen.* *Hat zu* ist eine feste Verbphrase, genau wie im Englischen.

Answer (score 1):

### Why »niemandem«?

In german the dative case can be used for multiple purposes. Here it marks the beneficiary or aggrieved party. (Who is the person, that should receive the accountability?) And here *nobody* (*niemand*) has the right to demand accountability, i.e. *nobody* is the beneficiary, and so *nobody* (*niemand*) has to stand in dative case:

> wrong (accusative case): Jemand, der <del>niemanden</del> Rechenschaft abzulegen hat.
>   correct (dative case): Jemand, der **niemandem** Rechenschaft abzulegen hat.

---

### Why »abzulegen hat«?

This is an absolutely correct sentence:

> Seine Haltung ist die eines Mannes, der niemandem Rechenschaft **abgelegt hat.**
>   His attitude is that of a man who **has not accounted** to anyone.

So, this man behaves, like he had not accounted to anyone in the past. But it is unclear, if it should have done it. Maybe he is obliged to account, but he just didn't fulfill his duty.

Compare with this sentence:

> Seine Haltung ist die eines Mannes, der niemandem Rechenschaft **abzulegen hat.**
>   His attitude is that of a man who **don't have not account** to anyone.

Here he behaves like a man who is his own boss, i.e. like a man, why is not obliged to tell anybody what he is doing.