# Wenn ein Vater ein Kind (leicht) schlägt, sagt man "schlagen" "ohrfeigen" "Klaps machen" oder was?

Tags: difference, vocabulary

Wenn ein Kind (insbesondere ein Kleinkind) den Eltern nicht gehorcht und die Mutter das Kind an der Wange (leicht) schlägt, nicht um es zu verletzen, sondern zu erschrecken, sagt man

- schlagen
- ohrfeigen
- Klaps machen
- etwas anderes

Comment: Ich habe "zu schockieren" in "erschrecken" geändert, auch wenn schockieren weder ganz falsch, noch erschrecken die beste Idee ist. Nur die beste, die mir kam.

Comment: Ich kann absolut nicht nachvollziehen, warum die Originalformulierung abgeschwächt wurde. Ich hatte wirklich gehofft, dass die Zeiten der Verharmlosung von Gewalt (gegen Kinder) vorbei sind.

Comment: @userunknown: ich bin ganz bei Olafant und verstehe nicht, welcher Kontext zwingend ergibt, dass etwas anderes als `schockieren` gemeint ist. Ich kann mich beim zuschlagen auch damit rechtfertigen, ich wolle damit die Aufmerksamkeit des Kindes oder es darauf hinweisen, es hätte was Schlimmes gemacht - beides würde ich nie mit "erschrecken" umschreiben. Plädiere für Rollback.

Comment: Zwingend sicher nicht, aber leicht schlagen würde ich nicht als zuschlagen bezeichnen.

Comment: _Schlagen ist Schlagen_ da gibt es keinerlei Abstufungen, Punkt Basta.

Comment: Dieses pauschale Abwerten aller Antworten und auch der Fragen in letzter Zeit geht mir langsam gehörig auf den S...

Answer (score 4):

Dem Kind *einen Klaps geben* wäre die einzige Formulierung, die darauf passen würde. Allerdings würde auch ein Klaps eher nicht auf die Wange, sondern eher auf die Finger (vor allem, wenn das Kind unerlaubt nach etwas greift) oder den Po gegeben werden.

Comment: Danke. Wenn ich gegoogelt habe, hat "ohrfeigen" heftig gesehen. Schlagen hat viele Bedeutungen (einen Ball schlagen, etc.). Ich wohne in den USA und habe kaum Gelegenheit diese Wörter zu üben.

Comment: Ohrfeigen müsste mit "leicht" attribuiert werden, denn man kann auch heftig ohrfeigen, so dass selbst ein Erwachsener zu Boden geht. Klaps dagegen transportiert den eher symbolischen Charakter. Allerdings sage ich, dass ein Klaps auch auf die Wange gegeben werden kann.

Answer (score 2):

In meinem Sprachumfeld (Brandenburg und Mecklenburg-Vorpommern) nannte man das

> hauen

und zwar in Wendungen wie

- jemand hauen
- jemandem eine hauen
- jemandem eine runterhauen

Wenn ich diese und ähnliche Aktivitäten aufsteigend nach Heftigkeit sortieren müsste, sähe das wie folgt aus:

1. einen Klaps geben
2. eine hauen
3. eine runterhauen

    ohrfeigen

    eine Backpfeife geben
4. schlagen
5. verprügeln

    verdreschen

So subjektiv diese Rangliste ist, so willkürlich scheint mir die Grenze für die bloße Absicht des Erschreckes zu sein. Schließlich kann man sein Gegenüber bei jeder dieser Aktivitäten *körperlich* verletzen, auch wenn das gar nicht beabsichtigt ist, von den *psychischen* Verletzungen mal ganz zu schweigen.

Comment: ... jemand**en** hauen?

Comment: @Olafant: ich ziehe aus `Sprachumfeld` das Indiz, dass beim Sprechen die Endung verschluckt wird. Oder es ist Dialekt - in meinem Kopf macht `jemand hauen` keinerlei Fragezeichen auf, sondern klingt völlig normal :-)  (damit einhergehend, dass auch bei den anderen beiden die Endung fehlt ;-)

Comment: @Olafant, ich verwende *jemand* und *niemand* im Akkusativ stets ohne Flexionsendung. Vgl. https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/723/beugt-man-jemand-oder-niemand-mit-endung

Comment: In meinem Sprachumfeld (moselfränkisch) waren hauen und runterhauen deutlich heftigere Aktivitäten als ein Klaps.

Comment: @userunknown, danke für den Kommentar. Ich habe meiner Antwort diesbezüglich noch etwas hinzugefügt.

Comment: Offenbar ist schon wieder jemand unterwegs und wertet alle Antworten ab. Ich bitte um eine Begründung!

Answer (score 0):

Der Zweck spielt keine Rolle. Letztlich ist auch eine "leichte" Ohrfeige eine Ohrfeige.

*Einen Klaps geben* ist eine Verniedlichung, die ausdrücken soll, dass solche körperlichen Gewaltakte ja gar nicht so schlimm wären. Man kann sich das leicht klarmachen, indem man sich fragt, ob die Mutter auch einem 2 Meter großen Mann *einen Klaps* geben würde, um ihren Willen durchzusetzen.

Auch die Formulierung

> nicht um es zu verletzen, sondern zu erschrecken

ist eine Art verniedlichender Rechtfertigung. Du sagst es schon ganz richtig:

> um es zu schockieren

Auch das ist eine Verletzung, insbesondere wenn das Kind einfach dem Drang seiner erwachenden Neugier folgt und dann den Schock erfährt, dafür von der Mutter geschlagen zu werden.

*Schlagen* oder *ohrfeigen* ist die richtige und zutreffende Formulierung.

Comment: Du diskutierst die Rechtfertigung von Klapsen oder Ohrfeigen, die gar nicht zur Disposition steht. Dabei benutzt Du auch noch Argumente, die keine sind. Das Wort Verletzung bedeutet, dass das Kind eine Verletzung davon trägt, also mindestens einen Bluterguß, eine Schürfwunde oder dergleichen. Minimalistisch gedacht eine kurzfristige Hautrötung vielleicht. Etwas, bei dem selbst das nicht vorliegt als körperlichen Gewaltakt zu bezeichnen ist grotesk. Und wenn ein 2m-Mann mit einer anzüglichen Bemerkung ihre Grenze überschreitet, dann kann ein Klaps eine angemessene Reaktion sein - wieso nicht?

Comment: @userunknown Ich diskutiere Formulierungen wie gefragt. Deine ebenso absurden wie traurigen Ansichten zu Gewalt und Verletzungen tun mir leid für dich und jedes Kind, das Leuten mit solchen Ansichten ausgeliefert ist.

Comment: Das ist nicht meine Ansicht dazu, was eine Verletzung ist, sondern die Definition von Verletzung. Siehe auch Verletzung der Lackschicht, Grenzverletzung usw. Du scheinst der Ansicht zu sein, dass sich aus der Begriffsdefinition eine Bewertung und indirekt ein Verhalten ableiten lässt; dass Verletzung bedeutet man ist nicht einverstanden und umgekehrt, wenn man nicht einverstanden ist, muss man es Verletzung nennen. So ist es aber nicht. Die Körperverletzung die der Friseur täglich zigfach begeht ist in Ordnung, weil sie einvernehmlich geschieht.

Comment: Ich stimme dieser Antwort allumfänglich zu. Alle anderen Formulierungen verharmlosen und kaschieren  das Problem. Schlagen ist Schlagen, und ist nicht aktzeptabel, Punkt. @userunknown

Comment: Es gibt auch seelische Verletzungen. Man muss nicht jede Verletzung von außen sehen können.

Comment: Dass Gewalt Menschen und insbesondere Kindern gegenüber absolut unzulässig ist, steht außer Frage. Jedoch gibt es verschiedene Verben, die ihre Form, Intensität und Art ausdrücken. Das gilt für jede Sprache. Man soll nicht Sprache mit Ethik verwechseln.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: Es geht hier nicht darum die richtige Bewertung zu finden, sondern die Maßstäbe nicht zu verlieren und allgemeinen Sprachgebrauch neutral darzustellen, so dass die Lerner was damit anfangen können. Wenn Du eine Erzählung der 50er-Jahre liest, willst Du wissen, ob der Lehrer einen Klaps oder eine Ohrfeige ausgeteilt hat. Dass Du beides schlecht findest heißt ja wohl nicht, dass beides gleich schlecht ist.

Comment: @infinitezero: Aus Verletzungen, die man nicht sieht darf man nicht folgern, dass alles, was man nicht sieht eine Verletzung ist. Ich erinnere in dem Zusammenhang an einen aufmunternden Klaps, den freundlichen Klaps und an einen neckischen Klaps auf den Po. Ihr könnt Euch 3x auf den Kopf stellen, wenn der geklapste sich nicht verletzt fühlt, dann ist es nun mal keine Gewalterfahrung. Gleich erfindet jmd. den Begriff Microtraumatisierung. Triggerwarning exzessive Gewalt: [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=47RwnFWTYiU] (Ozzimans Telekolegg Klaps).

Comment: @userunknown Deine Ablenkungsmanöver haben nichts mit der Ausgangsfrage zu tun, in der es darum geht, dass ein Kleinkind ins Gesicht geschlagen wird, um es zu schockieren, nicht um einen *aufmunternden* oder *neckischen* Klaps. Der einzige, der hier etwas erfindet, bist du.

Comment: @Olafant: Dann liest Du etwas in die Frage rein, was ich da nicht rausgelesen habe. Es ist ausdrücklich von einem leichten Schlag die Rede; ich interpretiere das als einen symbolischen Klaps. User1713450 hat auch nicht "schockieren" wieder hergestellt. Einen Klaps als Gewaltakt und seelische Verletzung zu klassifizieren, das ist letztlich auch eine Verharmlosung wirklicher Gewaltakte und wirklicher, seelischer Verletzungen. Alle Differenzierungen einzuebnen ist dann auch ein Gewaltakt.

Comment: @Nico Es geht darum, die Dinge beim Namen zu nennen, nicht um Ethik. Du siehst ja hier, wie das läuft. Wenn man einen (wenn auch leichten) Schlag ins Gesicht Gewalt nennt, wird das ins Lächerliche gezogen. Es ist doch schließlich nur ein Klaps! Ein Klaps ist keine Gewalt. So läuft das. Und alle Leute, die so abgestumpft sind, dass sie es ganz normal finden, wenn ein Kind ins Gesicht geschlagen wird, klatschen Beifall. Dass Gewalt (insbesondere Kindern gegenüber) unzulässig ist, steht eben leider nicht außer Frage. Umso wichtiger ist es, sich auf dieses sprachliche Rumgeeier nicht einzulassen.

Answer (score -3):

*schlagen* ist äußerst vielseitig in verschiedenen Bedeutungen. Es passt also gleichzeitig nicht so gut (etwa i.S.v. "besiegen") und irgendwie doch (es heißt ja nicht *schlachten* - *to slay*, lol).

*Ein Buch aufschlagen*, *aufklappen* hat bspw. keine wirklich gewaltigen Hintergründe. Ob sich sogar ein Bezug zu *ziehen, erziehen*, En. *teach* herstellen ließe, sei dahingestellt. *Jemandem eine reinziehen* ist tatsächlich negativ konnotiert, *zecken* nicht ganz so (*e zeckt, piekst*)

Oft macht der Ton die Musik, und Schlag mit langem A klingt weniger niedlich als bspw. eine *Schlappe* (vgl. *Schlapphut*, evtl. ein Hut mit ausgeklappter, ja umgekrempelter Krempe; nothing sloppy about it).